# group same name from array and show total of an indivisual group

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel

I have an array which look like this:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [products_name] => Parla to gold(Flower)
                [measurement] => 18
                [unit] => mm
                [products_size_height] => 0
                [products_size_width] => 0
                [products_size_unit] => inch
                [products_type] => 4
                [products_thickness_measurement] => 18
                [product_ordered_pcs] => 4
                [product_ordered_quantity] => 100
                [others_feature] => 
                [rate] => 500
                [amount] => 50000
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [products_name] => Parla to gold(Flower)
                [measurement] => 18
                [unit] => mm
                [products_size_height] => 0
                [products_size_width] => 0
                [products_size_unit] => inch
                [products_type] => 4
                [products_thickness_measurement] => 18
                [product_ordered_pcs] => 0
                [product_ordered_quantity] => 45
                [others_feature] => 
                [rate] => 45
                [amount] => 2025
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [products_name] => Parla to gold(Flower)
                [measurement] => 18
                [unit] => mm
                [products_size_height] => 0
                [products_size_width] => 0
                [products_size_unit] => inch
                [products_type] => 2
                [products_thickness_measurement] => 18
                [product_ordered_pcs] => 4
                [product_ordered_quantity] => 100
                [others_feature] => 
                [rate] => 850
                [amount] => 85000
            )
.......
```

Now I want to group the same product (product will be identified by combination of products_name, measurement and products_type) to show one product at a time and make total of "product_ordered_quantity" of the same product. See the image you may understand what I am trying to say. I will generate PDF file so no javascript please.

result:

[image]

I want:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to do? Please post some evidence that you at least tried

Comment: You can make array and by fillter or map php function to group your products in that array...than just show data how you want

Comment: I have an array which I got from laravel collection now I want to show the result on a table exactly that showing on the second image.

Comment: If you get this data from a db query, it is much easier to achieve what you need. If you confirm that it is coming from a query to the DB, i can provide you an answer

Comment: yes it is coming from a query to the DB @gbalduzzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a query from the DB you can use some methods provided by the Collection class (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections)

```
$query; //The query object BEFORE getting the data, so before get() or paginate()
$data = $query->selectRaw('sum(product_ordered_quantity) as quantity')
              ->groupBy('products_name','measurement', 'products_type')
              ->get();
```

Comment: I got total quantity but what about the Length x Width ? it only shows one Length x Width. Is there any way to show this? I have multiple Length x Width of same product. Please help @gbalduzzi

Comment: I think you will need to do 2 queries, one for the groups and one for the single lines

Comment: thanks bro I got Idea from your answer and then I solved it

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to this beautiful class, which will let you query to your array same as you query to the database - https://phplinq.codeplex.com/